# format word in a file (word document) using python docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have a text that is in a Word file. Using the Python library python-docx, I can format only certain portions of the text, specifically making them bold ? If I try to iterate through the Run objects created in order to manipulate the text to bold (using run.bold=True), I find that the formatting is applied only to the last object in the iterated list. What would be the correct approach in this case to achieve the desired result?

The code is :
'''
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def notafundamentare(*valori_inserate):
# Deschideți fișierul Word
document = Document('nota de fundamentare.docx')

```
# Lista cu valorile de căutat
valori_cautate = ['Conventiei nr',
                  'din data de',
                  'Borderoul aferent lunii',
                  'anul',
                  'către firma',
                  'Vâlcea cu nr',
                  'valoarea de']
runlist = []    
# Verificați dacă lungimile listelor sunt egale
if len(valori_cautate) == len(valori_inserate):
    # Parcurgeți lista de valori de căutat și inserat
    
    for i, valoare_cautata in enumerate(valori_cautate):
        paragrafe_gasite = []
        for paragraf in document.paragraphs:
            if valoare_cautata in paragraf.text:
                paragrafe_gasite.append(paragraf)

        if paragrafe_gasite:
            for paragraf_gasit in paragrafe_gasite:
                text_existent = paragraf_gasit.text
                index_aparitie = text_existent.index(valoare_cautata)
                paragraf_1 = paragraf_gasit.text[:index_aparitie]
                paragraf_3 = paragraf_gasit.text[index_aparitie + len(valoare_cautata):]

                # Înlocuiți textul paragrafului existent cu textul nou
                paragraf_gasit.text = paragraf_1

                # Creează obiectul Run și adaugă textul valorii căutate în locul său original
                run_gasit = paragraf_gasit.add_run(valoare_cautata)

                # Adăugați textul de inserat după valoarea căutată
                run_inserat = paragraf_gasit.add_run(" " + valori_inserate[i] + " ")
                run_inserat.bold = True

                # Adăugați textul rămas după valoarea căutată
                paragraf_gasit.add_run(paragraf_3)

                # Adaugă obiectul Run în lista runlist
                runlist.append(run_inserat)
                
for element in runlist:
    element.font.bold=True
    
# Salvați documentul Word actualizat
document.save('nota de fundamentare1.docx')
```

'''